# Skeljs Template from HTML5up

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using HALCYONIC from html5up.net which uses a skeljs framework.  The template uses a skeljs config file in the following format.  The format is then locked to 1200px, is there anyway to lock it to 1000px without having to dig through css and change alot of settings or alter this config greatly?  Thanks.

```
    window._skel_config = {
preset: 'standard',
prefix: 'css/style',
resetCSS: true,
breakpoints: {
    '800px': {
        grid: {
            gutters: 25
        }
    }
}
    };

    window._skel_panels_config = {
preset: 'standard'
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because of preset: 'standard'

http://skeljs.org/docs (search for presets)

You could remove the preset and instead custom define the containers property to be anything either overall for the _skel_config or for each breakpoint.